# How to set up Spring Cloud Gateway application so it can use the Service Discovery of Spring Cloud Kubernetes?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, service-discovery, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I created two Spring Boot applications which both will be deployed in a Kubernetes cluster. One of those apps will act as a gateway and therefore uses Spring Cloud Gateway as a dependency. Also I want to integrate service discovery with Spring Cloud Kubernetes and that the gateway uses the service discovery to automatically generate corresponding routes. But when I expose the gateway application, which is running in an local Minikube cluster, and invoke the second app/service I get a 503 error with following message: `Unable to find instance for ...-service`

Currently I have installed following:

- Minikube
- VirtualBox
- Docker Toolbox

I have created a Gradle project with two subprojects (gateway and another service). All projects will be build/deployed locally. The default Service Account has permission to read the Kubernetes API. After deployment of those services I expose the gateway service externally. In the gateway service I have some endpoints implemented, which

1. provide a list of all services in the cluster vie the DiscoveryClient.
2. on application layer invoke the other service based on the URI provided by the DiscoveryClient.

Everything seems to work but when I invoke the other service with `URI/serviceId` I get the 503 error...

Following Spring Cloud versions are used:
spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes 1.0.1.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-gateway 2.1.1.RELEASE

My demo app is available at https://github.com/nmaoez/spring-cloud-gateway-kubernetes and the README.md provides steps to get both services deployed in a local Minikube cluster. Also all available endpoints are shown. But the interessing part are the application.yaml and the application class of the gateway.

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

GatewayApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class GatewayApplication {

  @Autowired
  RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

  @GetMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String hello() {
    return "GatewayApplication says hello!";
  }

  @GetMapping("/test")
  @ResponseBody
  public String invokeTestService() {
    List<ServiceInstance> testServiceInstances = this.discoveryClient.getInstances("test-service");
    return restTemplate.getForObject(testServiceInstances.get(0).getUri(), String.class);
  }

  @GetMapping("/services")
  public List<String> services() {
    return this.discoveryClient.getServices();
  }

  @GetMapping("/services/{serviceId}")
  public List<ServiceInstance> servicesById(@PathVariable("serviceId") String serviceId) {
    return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceId);
  }

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I got it some how running after I overwrote the url-expression field in the gateway-service/application.yaml to

```
url-expression: "uri+'/'"
```

After that I got a correct response after I invoked `gateway-uri/another-service/`. But my wish is to not explicitly replace the default of `lb://serviceid`. How can I do that?

I expect that if I invoke another service in the cluster though the gateway, I get a 200 response and the correct answer based in the rest controller of the application.

Comment: I have a similar issue on GKE, did you find a solution? see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594228/spring-cloud-kubernetes-spring-cloud-gateway-unable-to-find-instance-for-k8s/57594399#57594399

Comment: I'm stuck did u got the solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the dependency to `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon` as well.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then it will work without any rewrites, just with the `spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled: true`

Comment: I have a similar issue and this answer doesn’t help

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented an example application using Spring Cloud Gateway and Kubernetes, that works like a charm in Docker Desktop. And no extra nor funny configurations were needed.

If it may help this was my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.0")
    set('springCloudKubernetesVersion', '1.1.7.RELEASE')
    set('springCloudVersion', '2020.0.0')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes:$springCloudKubernetesVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config:$springCloudKubernetesVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon:$springCloudKubernetesVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-loadbalancer:$springCloudKubernetesVersion"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudVersion"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is the configuration from the `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
```

And finally, the `DiscoveryClient` is enabled in the app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient // So services can be discovered
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Note as Jakub Kubrynski said, you must include the Ribbon dependency.

Also beware routing only works when the gateway is deployed to the K8s cluster. Outside it, it can see the K8s services but cannot route to them since they are using IP addresses in the K8s network.

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to setup spring cloud gateway with discovery of spring-cloud-kubernetes dependency version 1.1.10.RELASE and Spring-boot: 2.5.7 Spring cloud gateway: 3.0.4

Pom file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.csg.cro.rccs</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <name>RCC-APIGateway</name>
    <description>Enable Proxy and verify user token project for Risk 360</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <revision>21.7.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-loadbalancer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

My discovery config look like:

```
spring:
  application.name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          url-expression: "'http://'+serviceId+':'+getPort()"
          lower-case-service-id: true
```